# Какие опции нужно указать в rsync, чтобы передать .env file безопасно?

Tags: rsync

Как известно, обычно ".env" файл может содержать критические данные　(особенно в случае продакшена), утечка которых опасна. Тем не менее, может возникнуть необходимость загрузить его на сервер. В основном, я собираюсь использовать для загрузки файлов на сервер утилиту rsync, но способна ли эта утилита обеспечить достаточную безопасность при передаче критических данных и если да, то какие должны нужно указать опции?

Comment: А в чем опасения?

Comment: @user207200 Если честно, то не уверен, что опасения всегда имеют основания. Вот скажите например зачем нужно исключать .env файл для режима локальной разработки из отслеживания системой контроля версий, если пароли, которые там содержатся, актуальны только для одного компьютера и даже если получить доступ к данным, то как правило это будут случайные тестовые данные? Тем не менее, все так делают. Я, конечно, постепенно задаюсь вопросами "а почему так?", но на всё время не хватает.

Comment: @user207200 Что касается данного вопроса, то задам его по-другому: могу ли я быть уверен, что не произойдёт утечки критических данных (такие как пароли к базам данных), если я использую rcync для загрузки .env-файла на сервер?

Comment: Смотря что вы понимаете под "утечкой". Весь ваш исходящий трафик бережно сохраняется провайдером связи. Это утечка?

Comment: @user207200 Вообще да, но так как соответствующий пункт обычно указан в договоре с заказчиком, то такой вид утечки едва ли приведёт к крупным проблемам.

Comment: Утечка уже произошла, если у вас на компьютере есть копия этого файла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы передать .env файл безопасно с использованием rsync, следует указать следующие опции:

- -a (архивный режим) - копирует файлы и их метаданные, такие как права доступа и время изменения.
- -e ssh - указывает rsync использовать SSH для соединения.
- -v (verbose) - выводит подробную информацию о копировании файлов.
- -z - включает сжатие данных во время передачи.
- -P - показывает прогресс копирования файлов.

Пример команды:

```
rsync -azve ssh --progress .env user@remote:/path/to/dir/
```

Если вы хотите сохранить права доступа и владельца файла, используйте опцию `-p`

```
rsync -azve ssh --progress -p .env user@remote:/path/to/dir/
```

Но не стоит забывать, что при работе с файлами конфигурации с паролями, критической информацией и т.д. следует использовать зашифрованное соединение и обеспечить соответствующую защиту на стороне сервера и клиента. Рекомендуется использовать инструменты шифрования такие как ssh-ключи, сертификаты, туннелирование и т.д. и следить за безопасностью системы и сети.

Answer (score 2):

Rsync может обеспечить безопасность, для этого необходимо указать опцию `"--rsh='ssh -c cypher'"` и выбрать шифр
.
Например, чтобы использовать шифрование AES-256 можно использовать команду:

```
rsync --rsh='ssh -c aes256-ctr' -avz .env user@remote:/path/to/directory
```

Еще можно использовать аутентификацию по ssh-ключам и сжатие данных при передаче через rsync

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa" --compress-level=9 .env user@remote:/path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 1):

rsync умеет работать через ssh соединение.
SSH соединение шифруется и считается защищённым.
Пример команды

```
rsync -ahvze ssh /local_path  username@ip:/remote_machine_path
```